# Output specific child-element in alert() on click (pure JS)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get an alert as soon as I click on a list-element, containing only the title of that list element.

I tired a lot, but I'm just starting to learn and I only got so far to output the complete innerHTML of the element.

https://jsfiddle.net/9cbjde5s/2/

```js
function createEventHandler(items, i) {
  return function() {
    alert(items[i].innerHTML);
  };
}
onload = function() {
  var view = document.getElementById('view');
  var items = view.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].onclick = createEventHandler(items, i);
  }
};
```

```css
.list-item {
  background-color: Gray;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id='view'>
  <li class="list-item">
    <p class="author">some author</p>
    <p class="title">Title1</p>
    <p class="date">01.01.2020</p>
  </li>

  <li class="list-item">
    <p class="author">some author2</p>
    <p class="title">Title2</p>
    <p class="date">01.01.2020</p>
  </li>

  <li class="list-item">
    <p class="author">some author</p>
    <p class="title">Title3</p>
    <p class="date">01.01.2020</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution would be even better, so you don't count the nodes, but refer to a child by class name:

```js
function createEventHandler(items, i) {
  return function() {
    alert(items[i].querySelector('.title').innerHTML);
  };
}
onload = function() {
  var view = document.getElementById('view');
  var items = view.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].onclick = createEventHandler(items, i);
  }
};
```

```css
.list-item {
  background-color: Gray;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id='view'>
  <li class="list-item">
    <p class="author">some author</p>
    <p class="title">Title1</p>
    <p class="date">01.01.2020</p>
  </li>

  <li class="list-item">
    <p class="author">some author2</p>
    <p class="title">Title2</p>
    <p class="date">01.01.2020</p>
  </li>

  <li class="list-item">
    <p class="author">some author</p>
    <p class="title">Title3</p>
    <p class="date">01.01.2020</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the child node, containing the title, like that:

```js
function createEventHandler(items, i) {
  return function() {
    alert(items[i].childNodes[3].innerHTML);
  };
}
onload = function() {
  var view = document.getElementById('view');
  var items = view.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].onclick = createEventHandler(items, i);
  }
};
```

```css
.list-item {
  background-color: Gray;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id='view'>
  <li class="list-item">
    <p class="author">some author</p>
    <p class="title">Title1</p>
    <p class="date">01.01.2020</p>
  </li>

  <li class="list-item">
    <p class="author">some author2</p>
    <p class="title">Title2</p>
    <p class="date">01.01.2020</p>
  </li>

  <li class="list-item">
    <p class="author">some author</p>
    <p class="title">Title3</p>
    <p class="date">01.01.2020</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Still, better use the other solution :)

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for, thanks for your time!